# Find the number of vertices n of the tree?

Tags: graph-theory, proof-verification

Suppose a tree has $n$ vertices where half of these vertices are of degree $2$, six are of degree $3$, and the remaining are leaves. Find the number of vertices $n$ of the tree. Please do not find the answer by drawing. Use the
degree equation.

$ \sum \textrm {degree}(v) = 2e$

let $n=2n+6$

$e=n-1$

$e=(n+6)-1$

$=n+5$

$\sum n+3(6)=2(n+5)$

$n+36=2n+10$

$26=n$

Is this correct?
If not, could you help me?

Comment: How are you going to let $n=2n+6$?

Comment: It looks like $e$ and $|E|$ are both the number of edges.  Please use a consistent symbol.

Comment: We have already had this question earlier today. The answer remains the same: the number of vertices is 28. It is a tree so there are 27 edges. We have 14 vertices degree 2, 6 of degree 3 and 8 of degree 1. Check: 28+18+8=54.

Comment: how make your answer to same way in me solution؟

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your statement ‘let $n=2n+6$’ makes no sense: no number satisfies that equation. Your $26$ is not quite right.

You know that the tree has $\frac{n}2$ vertices of degree $2$ and $6$ vertices of degree $3$, and that the remaining

$$n-\frac{n}2-6=\frac{n}2-6$$

vertices are leaves, which have degree $1$. You also know that $e=n-1$. Thus,

$$2\cdot\frac{n}2+3\cdot6+1\cdot\left(\frac{n}2-6\right)=\sum_v\deg v=2e=2(n-1)\;,$$

and solving for $n$ is just basic algebra.

Comment: Hello! "ping" me when you next visit chat.

Comment: Does this graph actually exists?

Comment: @Aqua: There are quite a few trees that satisfy these conditions. Start with a rooted tree with $14$ vertices such that: the root has $3$ children; each child of the root has $2$ children; and the $2$ children of one child of the root have $2$ children each. That tree has $6$ vertices of degree $3$ and $8$ leaves. Now insert $14$ vertices of degree $2$ by splitting any edge `*---*` in to two edges, `*---*---*`.

Answer (score 1):

If you replace each vertex of degree $2$ by an edge joining the two neighbours of that vertex, you get a tree with $n/2$ vertices, of which $6$ have degree $3$ and the rest are leaves...